# Heavy load by APT unattended-upgrade

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

`16.04 Xenial`

> APT automatic update check: enabled
>
> APT automatic update download & install: disabled
>
> No cron jobs listed below,
>
> $ for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do sudo crontab -u $user -l; done

The system suddenly `top`ped by heavy load pertaining to both CPU and Network IO from the aroused `unattended-upgrade` for several minutes.

Why could it happen when automatic update download & install were totally disabled?

Comment: A better question is why does it hammer the CPU. Disabling it is just a work-around for a bigger issue. I'm getting this on 18.04 VM this morning. Running 100% for about 10 mins when booted. Now at about 25% for last 20 mins. Reminds me of Windows updates.

Comment: @bshea Its actually worse than Windows updates.

Comment: The high CPU usage is a known bug. I posted a solution to this here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1359119/1060743

Comment: @stackprotector Do we know why was that answer downvoted?

Comment: @Stewart A user stated, that the solution did not work for him. I was able to reproduce the problem inside a VM and to solve it by my solution (which does not disable unattended upgrades in contrast to many other solutions).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The functionality on `unattended-upgrades` is automatically enabled after the installation of `16.04 Xenial Server`. I mistakenly didn't really disable it so observed the unexpected behaviors above. `Method Two` [here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/disable-automatic-updates-ubuntu.html) I had followed is unlikely effective.

To properly disable the [automatic updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates), we need change the configuation on `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades` from:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

to:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "0";
```

Answer (score 14):

If your OS uses systemd then:

```
sudo systemctl mask unattended-upgrade.service
```

would also stop it from automatically running.

The main issue I have is: why is it taking up 100% CPU for downloading some files?