# unattended-upgrade CPU 100% for 4 hours (every time) [in case of many routing tables]

Tags: cpu-load, unattended-upgrades

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

During unattended-upgrade the CPU use 100% of resource for 4 hours

Example:

```
$ unattended-upgrade --dry-run --debug

2019-02-16 10:34:46,087 INFO Enabled logging to syslog via daemon facility
2019-02-16 10:34:46,087 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:
2019-02-16 10:34:46,088 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:
2019-02-16 10:34:46,088 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2019-02-16 10:34:46,088 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2019-02-16 10:34:56,044 INFO Enabled logging to syslog via daemon facility
2019-02-16 10:34:56,045 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:
2019-02-16 10:34:56,045 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:
2019-02-16 10:34:56,045 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
*2019-02-16 10:34:56,046 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2019-02-16 10:34:56,290 DEBUG Using (^linux-image|^linux-headers|^linux-image-extra|^linux-modules|^linux-modules-extra|^linux-signed-image|^kfreebsd-image|^kfreebsd-headers|^gnumach-image|^.*-modules|^.*-kernel|^linux-backports-modules-
.*|^linux-modules-.*|^linux-tools|^linux-cloud-tools) regexp to find kernel packages
2019-02-16 10:34:56,294 DEBUG Using (^linux-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-headers.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-image-extra.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules-extra.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-signed-image.*4
.15.0-45-generic|^kfreebsd-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^kfreebsd-headers.*4.15.0-45-generic|^gnumach-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|4.15.0-45-generic.*-modules|4.15.0-45-generic.*-kernel|^linux-backports-modules-.*.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modul
es-.*.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-tools.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-cloud-tools.*4.15.0-45-generic) regexp to find running kernel packages
2019-02-16 10:34:57,345 DEBUG pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:
2019-02-16 10:37:17,591 INFO Enabled logging to syslog via daemon facility
2019-02-16 10:37:17,592 INFO Initial blacklisted packages:
2019-02-16 10:37:17,593 INFO Initial whitelisted packages:
2019-02-16 10:37:17,593 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2019-02-16 10:37:17,593 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
2019-02-16 10:37:17,836 DEBUG Using (^linux-image|^linux-headers|^linux-image-extra|^linux-modules|^linux-modules-extra|^linux-signed-image|^kfreebsd-image|^kfreebsd-headers|^gnumach-image|^.*-modules|^.*-kernel|^linux-backports-modules-
.*|^linux-modules-.*|^linux-tools|^linux-cloud-tools) regexp to find kernel packages
2019-02-16 10:37:17,840 DEBUG Using (^linux-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-headers.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-image-extra.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules-extra.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-signed-image.*4
.15.0-45-generic|^kfreebsd-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^kfreebsd-headers.*4.15.0-45-generic|^gnumach-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|4.15.0-45-generic.*-modules|4.15.0-45-generic.*-kernel|^linux-backports-modules-.*.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modul
es-.*.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-tools.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-cloud-tools.*4.15.0-45-generic) regexp to find running kernel packages
2019-02-16 10:37:18,903 DEBUG pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:
2019-02-16 14:22:00,768 DEBUG fetch.run() result: 0
2019-02-16 14:22:00,769 DEBUG blacklist: []
2019-02-16 14:22:00,769 DEBUG whitelist: []
2019-02-16 14:22:00,771 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

> 2019-02-16 10:37:18,903 DEBUG pkgs that look like they should be upgraded:

> 2019-02-16 14:22:00,768 DEBUG fetch.run() result: 0

This is a "manual run" but the issue is also present during automatic-updates:

```
 3541 ?        Ss     0:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily update
 3546 ?        S      0:00  \_ /bin/sh /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily lock_is_held update
 4072 ?        Rl   158:20      \_ /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade --download-only
```

#### UPDATE 1

Today there are updates, but this is the result (``top):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
23271 root      20   0  269328 181084  49932 R 100.0  4.5   0:22.21 unattended-upgr
```

and still waiting here from hours with CPU 100%....

```
# unattended-upgrade --dry-run --debug
Enabled logging to syslog via daemon facility
Initial blacklisted packages:
Initial whitelisted packages:
Starting unattended upgrades script
Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=bionic, o=Ubuntu,a=bionic-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=bionic
Using (^linux-image|^linux-headers|^linux-image-extra|^linux-modules|^linux-modules-extra|^linux-signed-image|^kfreebsd-image|^kfreebsd-headers|^gnumach-image|^.*-modules|^.*-kernel|^linux-backports-modules-.*|^linux-modules-.*|^linux-tools|^linux-cloud-tools) regexp to find kernel packages
Using (^linux-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-headers.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-image-extra.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules-extra.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-signed-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^kfreebsd-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|^kfreebsd-headers.*4.15.0-45-generic|^gnumach-image.*4.15.0-45-generic|4.15.0-45-generic.*-modules|4.15.0-45-generic.*-kernel|^linux-backports-modules-.*.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-modules-.*.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-tools.*4.15.0-45-generic|^linux-cloud-tools.*4.15.0-45-generic) regexp to find running kernel packages
Checking: libnss-systemd ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
Checking: libpam-systemd ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
Checking: libpci3 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: libpci3=1:3.5.2-1ubuntu1
Checking: libsystemd0 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
Checking: libudev1 ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
Checking: pciutils ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: pciutils=1:3.5.2-1ubuntu1
Checking: systemd ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
Checking: systemd-sysv ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
Checking: udev ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-updates' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>, <Origin component:'main' archive:'bionic-security' origin:'Ubuntu' label:'Ubuntu' site:'archive.ubuntu.com' isTrusted:True>])
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: libnss-systemd
libpam-systemd
libsystemd0
libudev1
systemd
systemd-sysv
udev
```

I still think that Ubuntu is the worst Linux distribution.

#### Update 2

I discovered the issue!
The problem only happens when I have many routing tables.
Inexplicable, but reproducible on all installations.

Comment: Do you have a question? Or are you just informing us? In any event, why are you leaving an upgrading computer unattended?  `INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended`

Comment: This is a question...
The process takes 4 hours with 100% CPU even if there aren't updates

Comment: Why are you leaving it unattended? The developers of whatever program piped the output to `stdout` for a reason read it. Also check `journalctl -e` after an "update"

Comment: The issue is also present during automatic updates (/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade --download-only). The are no other outputs or logs...

Comment: Unfortunatley with no output/logs, I can't help you

Comment: FWIW, my laptop had a load of 80 this morning with `unattended-upgrades` being the only process at 100% CPU, so I masked/disabled the service. See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/849087/26987

Comment: Same issue. Runs at 100% CPU on boot up for about 1-20 mins.`Sep 22 11:53:12 vbox-ubuntu1 systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.` That's the log. Informative, huh?

Answer (score 10):

Consider turning off unattended upgrades in APT.  Disable it by doing a `grep -R Unattended /etc/apt` and looking for:

```
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

Then, change the 1 to a 0 (disable). You can then try to restart the unattended-upgrade service (`systemctl restart unattended-upgrades.service`), but sometimes it's actually faster to just reboot the whole machine.

Answer (score 3):

yet happening with version 2.8. I found this command to disable this functionality:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

source:
https://ostechnix.com/how-to-disable-unattended-upgrades-on-ubuntu/

Comment: perfect answer...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably **Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS** that cause the issue.Try to upgrade it to **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS** with apt-get upgrade and apt-get dist-upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=899366) of `unattended-upgrades` v1.1 (aka 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.11). Upgrade to v1.4 (aka 1.1ubuntu1.18.04.14):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade unattended-upgrades
```

You can check your current version with:

```
dpkg -s unattended-upgrades | grep '^Version:' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Comment: i'm on `1.1ubuntu1.18.04.14` and still see the issue

Comment: @rrosa Which issue exactly? 100% CPU usage for a long time or that `unattended-upgrades` just still runs from time to time?

Comment: the 100% CPU issue (can't edit comment, sorry)